# hide an html element previously shown with jquery on click of a different html element

Tags: jquery

I have a job site where a list of jobs titles are displayed, when a title is clicked certain elements set that were previously set to `display:"none"` are shown using the jquery `show()` function. How can I hide these elements again when a new job title is clicked on? So that one appears to collapse when a new job is expanded? link to larger jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s5gh2rLm/6/ but I believe included the most important parts of code below

```
<body>
                <div class="job">
                    <h2><a class="job_link" href="#">Accountant  - ABC Bank</a></h2>
                    <p class="start_hidden job_p">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur corporis dolor eius facere laboriosam libero minima necessitatibus nobis nulla, officiis optio quis tempore vel. Exercitationem harum ipsum perspiciatis unde voluptate!</p>
                    <p class="start_hidden">salary: 12</p>
                </div>
                <div class="job">
                    <h2><a class="job_link" href="#">Doctor  - XYZ Hosptial</a></h2>
                    <p class="start_hidden job_p">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur corporis dolor eius facere laboriosam libero minima necessitatibus nobis nulla, officiis optio quis tempore vel. Exercitationem harum ipsum perspiciatis unde voluptate!</p>
                    <p class="start_hidden">salary: 12</p>
                </div>
                <div class="job">
                    <h2><a class="job_link" href="#">Teacher  - ABC School</a></h2>
                    <p class="start_hidden job_p">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur corporis dolor eius facere laboriosam libero minima necessitatibus nobis nulla, officiis optio quis tempore vel. Exercitationem harum ipsum perspiciatis unde voluptate!</p>
                    <p class="start_hidden">salary: 12</p>
                </div>

</html>
```

js (used to so far only show previously hidden elements):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".job_link").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.job').find(".start_hidden").show();
    });
});
```

css:

```
.start_hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem! All you need to do is hide everything before showing the necessary elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".job_link").click(function(){
      $(".start_hidden").hide(); // Add this line
      $(this).parents('.job').find(".start_hidden").show();
    });
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Maybe even remove `start_hidden` altogether. Sounds like all job descriptions should be wrapped in a class, e.g. `job-description`, which is set to `display: none` via CSS. Then when you click a parent link, you run `$('.job-description').hide(); $('.job-description', $(this)).show();` to (1) hide anything that's already showing and then (2) show the new ones.